# Missing Known Solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving for the zeroes of the function:

> $$\frac{\cos(x)(3\cos^2(x)-1)}{(1+\cos^2(x))^2}$$

The zeroes of the function I found were done by setting $\cos(x)=0$, and $3\cos^2(x)-1=0$

For the $3\cos^2(x)-1=0$ I solved it and got $x=\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt3}{3})$ but my calculator only gives one solution $x=.955$ but when I graphed it I got another solution at $x=2.186$. How would I get the one solution I didn't get with the calculator?

Comment: Hint: $.955 + 2.186 \simeq \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re really solving $\cos^2x=\frac13$, so $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{\frac13}$. Your $0.955$ is approximately $\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac13}$; to finish the solution, you need to find $\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac13}\right)$. Use the identity $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$: if $\cos x=\sqrt{\frac13}$, then $\cos(\pi-x)=-\sqrt{\frac13}$, and your other solution is

$$\pi-\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac13}\approx 2.186\;.$$

Comment: Typo: $\cos(2\pi - x) = \cos x$, not $-\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$3\cos^2(x) - 1 = 0$$

means that

$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{3}$$

which does not necessarily mean

$$\cos(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$$

What other value could $\cos(x)$ take on?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have infinite solutions:

$$\cos x=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{2} +k\pi$$

$$\cos x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \Rightarrow x=\cos^{-1}\left(\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right) +2k\pi$$